# Need help for creating use case diagram of Mandarin Square Capturing

Tags: java, oop, uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I have to design an use case diagram of a game for the project at school
The game must have these functions:

1. On the main screen:

   - Start: start the game.
   - Exit: exit the program. Be sure to ask users if they really want to quit the game
   - Help: Show guide for playing the game
2. In the game:

   - Gameboard: The gameboard consists of 10 squares, divided into 2 rows, and 2 half-circle
     on the 2 ends of the board. Initially, each square has 5 small stones and each half-circle
     has 1 big stone. Each small stone equals 1 point, and each big gem equals 5 points.
   - For each turn, the game must show clearly whose turn it is. A player will select a
     square and a direction to spread the gems. He got points when after finishing spreading,
     there is one empty square followed by a square with gems. The score the got for that
     turn is equal to the number of gems in that followed square (see the gameplay for more
     details about streaks)
   - The game ends when there is no gem in both half-circles. The game must notify
     who is the winner and the score of each player.

Here is my use case diagram:

[image]

Did I write the right diagram?

Comment: See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831) The tip most relevant here is to trim the image to the important part.

Answer (score 0):

Use cases are about the actor's objectives and not about the user interface:

- `Play game` is clearly the main objective of `Player`.
- `View game rules` can arguably be a distinct objective. The `Player` may want to read it before starting a game. We could also imagine, that a `Player` may want to view it during the game, for example in case of doubts about the legality of a specific move.
- `Exit game` does not seem to be a separate objective.  I may want to install a game just to read the rules if there is no other way to find them out.  But I'd never install a game just for using the "Exit". Exit is just a mandatory feature, but not something that the user values.

The details of the rules suggest that there may be several players. You may therefore consider to add a multiplicity `1..2` or `1..*` on the `Player` side of the link between the `Play game` an `Player` (unless it is meant to be one human player vs. the computer).